# Submit POST and GET variables in one form

Tags: php, html, post, get

I'm working on a query tool that displays data from a MySQL database. The user is presented with a form containing a few dozen dynamically-generated checkboxes so that they can select how to view the data. This data is submitted as a GET request and is (obviously) displayed in the url when the requested page loads.

On the same page as the input form, I have a php array that I am generating dynamically and that needs to be sent to the same place as the GET request. However, I do not want the values in this array to be displayed in the URL (i'm using them internally) so I'd like to submit them as a POST request instead.

Obviously, I can't do both a GET and POST request at the same time. I'm new to web development (computer science guy, otherwise) and have been scratching my head on how to approach this.

Let me know if the problem isn't clear.

**EDIT: Many have suggested I add them to the action variable a la:**

**form action="process.php?get1=value...**

**All of these inputs are generated dynamically so to put them in the action variable is not feasible.**

Comment: You could store the array in session variables this way it would remain hidden from the user (If you don't send it as cookies), but why not just use hidden form elements and submit as post?

Comment: If it's a PHP array, just store it in a session.

Comment: You submit POST parameters through form inputs. You can send GET parameters in the same request by including them in the `form action="process.php?get1=value..."` parameter of the `<form>`.

Comment: I ended up using a session and it worked well. Thank you @Endophage and Alexander Varwijk. Endo, if you submit this as the answer I can give you a check mark.

Comment: Why is it not feasible to put them in the action variable? Dynamically generated or not, a query string is quite easy to build?

Comment: The way that this web app is designed wouldn't accommodate it very well. It would require a great deal of restructuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endophage:

> If it's a PHP array, just store it in a session.

This worked great. Obviously, I'm showing my web development greenness here as I didn't really consider using a session.

Answer (score 15):

GET parameters go in the action url, POST parameters in the form's inputs

```
<form method="post" action="/somepage.php?get=parameters&are=here">
    <input type="text" name="postParameter" value="this value will be sent as POST">
    ... etc
</form>
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I tried a similar thing just now and it just strips the get parameters (using chrome)

Comment: @Arninja Works fine. Chrome (and any other browser) sends both sets of parameters, and you can access parameters from either set using `$_REQUEST`, or access them individually with `$_GET` and `$_POST` respectively

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot do a post and a get in the same form** you even said that in your question.

You have to either:

1. Have 2 forms
2. Have one thing submit with a post via ajax and then submit the other form with a get

Comment: I'm aware that I can't do them in the same form. I want to achieve the same end.

Comment: @SemperFly and i gave you the ways to do it.

Comment: @Neal: Um, I think you mean "you _can_ do POST and GET in the same form". Well, ok, the actual http request will be either POST or GET, but that doesn't mean you can't have a query string in the url. The server in question is running PHP, so it'll read both sets of parameters just fine

Comment: @Neal: What do you mean by "dynamic information"? PHP can "dynamically" output a couple of inputs with values in POST form, as well as a url with a query string => GET + POST. The only thing I can imagine is that you want _some_ user input to be sent as GET and some to be sent as POST, in which case javascript can help you out, by moving values to the form's action url. Again: solved. If you can't or won't use javascript, and still need some inputs sent as POST and others as GET, then yeah, that's difficult, but then seriously: What are you even trying to do?!

Comment: @Flambino - testy testy - i am not trying to do anything, the OP is. and that is what the OP seems to want to do is send some of the inputs via post and some via get which is not possible without javascript

Comment: @Neal: No offense intended. I only meant the "wtf are you doing?!" part as a joke; not directed at you. Should've added a smiley or something :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set GET vars by changing URL:

```
<form action="foo.php?getvar=15" method="POST">
<input name="postvar">
</form>
```

For dynamic GET vars I believe you need Javascript.

Comment: Right, but all of these variables are generated dynamically so to put them in the action variable is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="page.php?id=15" method="POST">
<input name="ref_code_cust" type="text" value="some data">
<input name="send" type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

or

www.mywebsite/page.php?id=15

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>"> 
<input name="email" type="text" value="some data">
<input name="send" type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

we need to see your code also to make it easier, especial this array thing